# Can the matrix element of the momentum operator be found in the momentum basis?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

In Shankar's Quantum Mechanics example 7.3.4, the problem is to find $\langle n'\rvert P\lvert n\rangle$ for the harmonic oscillator. The answer contains imaginary parts; you can derive such an answer by solving it in the $x$ basis (making $P= -\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$).

But I think there is another way to approach this, writing the $\psi$ function in the $p$ basis and simply integrate $\psi P \psi\,\mathrm{d}P$ from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. By doing this I don't get any imaginary terms. Why not? Should this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you wouldn't get any imaginary terms in the matrix elements. Your suggestion of aproach is right and in this case the eigenstates $|n\rangle$ of the harmonic oscilator are represented by [Hermite Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions) in position representation, which happens to be [Fourier transform's eigenfunctions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions_as_eigenfunctions_of_the_Fourier_transform) as well. As the unitary map that changes form the position basis to the momentum basis is the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$, by writing the eigenstates in momentum representation, you will get the same functions but with a constant factor of difference, $(-i)^n$, which is the eigenvalue of $\psi_n$: $(\mathcal{F}\psi_n)(p)=(-i)^n\psi_n(p)$. So, when calculating the matrix elements, you will have (with $\hbar=1$):
\begin{align}\langle n'|P|n\rangle&=\int dp'\int dp\langle n'|p'\rangle\langle p'|P|p\rangle\langle p|n\rangle\\
&=\int dp'\int dp\langle n'|p'\rangle p\delta(p'-p)\langle p|n\rangle\\
&=\int dp\langle n'|p\rangle p\langle p|n\rangle\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty i^{n'}\psi_{n'}(p)\,p\,(-i)^n\psi_n(p)dp\end{align}
which will be purely imaginary if $n+n'$ is odd. You can realize that this happens, because the Hamiltonian $H=X^2+P^2$ is symmetric between a change in position and momentum, so its eigenfunctions should be the same in both representantions.

Comment: thanks a lot!! what I missed was that n> are represented with x basis